Wrong values for SELECT * FROM 'XXX' in 2 different PHPmyadmin Versions
even after several hours of investigation i can't solve a big problem regarding different counts for table rows in PHPmyadmin. The shop on the old server is online, working. Our shop system never deletes products when sold - it set them inactive. The new server is non productive.
Old Server:
MySQL Server-Version: 10.3.39-MariaDB-0+deb10u2 - Debian 10
PHPmyadmin  5.0.4deb2~bpo10+1
Apache/2.4.59 (Debian)
DB-Client Version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev
PHP-Extensions: mysqli curl mbstring
PHP-Version: 7.3
New server:
MySQL Server-Version: 10.11.6-MariaDB-0+deb12u1 - Debian 12
PHPmyadmin 5.2.1deb1
Apache/2.4.59 (Debian)
DB-Client Version: libmysql - mysqlnd 8.2.20
PHP-Extensions: mysqli curl mbstring sodium
PHP-Version: 8.2.20
I did an shell db export/import from the old server to the new server in an empty DB:
mysqldump -u user -p database > dump.sql
mysql -u user -p database < dump.sql

All looking smooth on the first try, last table written, 1,4gb written in about 30s.
But the when i go to SELECT * FROM products the count of rows in the new DB is about 150 less than in the old one. I exported multiple times. I imported multiple times. Always the same count.
So i came back to the old rule "if something doesn't work the IT way you'd like it to work: do it different.".
I exported the table products from the old server via PHPmyadmin SQL.zip export.
SELECT * from products, old server: 156.616
I imported the file into the new servers db (for sure after deleting old table products)
SELECT * from products, new server: 158.020 - the same count as on the overview page.
AS far as i understand the row counts on the tables overview in PHPmyadmin is always an "about" value.
But SELECT * from products should always deliver the correct numbers, right?
I went multiple times to operations > analyze tables on old and new server, which should flush the cache and recalculate values. I get different counts most times. Analyze always resulted in an "OK"
Old server 157.114 / 157.398 / 158.107 / 157.398
New Server 157.453 / 157.027 / 157.027 / 158.020
So i did an csv export of the old and new table. Absolutely no differences. But quite a hard way to compare the integrity of a DB migration with 293 tables and 1.4gb.
Any idea why PHPmyadmin is always counting wrong?
We did delete sold products once to save space. products.products_id is AUTO INCREMENT NOT NULL. Shouldn't cause the problem, right?
Cheers
Frank

This question is similar to: phpmyadmin: Incorrect table rowcount with MySQL. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
